# How does white mate in two?

Tags: tactics, problems

```
[FEN "7Q/p1p1b1B1/6r1/2p3kp/4Bp1q/7P/PPP2PP1/6K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

([source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgUdn.jpg))

In this problem, it’s White to move and mate in two. What is the solution?

Answer (score 6):

I would not normally answer this, but the real answer was deleted by its author for some reason, and is hidden. I also think that the original -3 for the question was more due to the original poster not being a native English speaker so I edited that too.

This is from the game Diaz Carias-Cordovil, 1966 Olympiad. Black resigned after 30.Bh6+, which is the first move of the solution. After Black’s forced Rxh6, White will play Qe5#.

```
 [Event "Olympiad-17 Final C"]
 [Site "Havana"]
 [Date "1966.11.13"]
 [Round "9"]
 [White "Diaz Carias, Salvador"]
 [Black "Cordovil, Joao Maria"]
 [Result "1-0"]
 [ECO "C50"]
 [StartPly "58"]
 [EventDate "1966.11.04"]
 [EventType "team-tourn"]
 [EventRounds "13"]
 [EventCountry "CUB"]
 [SourceTitle "MCD"]
 [WhiteTeam "Venezuela"]
 [BlackTeam "Portugal"]
 [WhiteTeamCountry "VEN"]
 [BlackTeamCountry "POR"]
 [FEN ""]

 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Be7 4. d4 d6 5. h3 exd4 6. Nxd4 Nf6 7. Nc3 O-O 8. O-O Nxe4 9. Nxc6 bxc6 10. Nxe4 d5 11. Bd3 dxe4 12. Bxe4 Rb8 13. Qf3 c5 14. Rd1 Bd6 15. Bd2 Qh4 16. Bc3 f5 17. Bd5+ Kh8 18. Re1 f4 19. Re2 h5 20. Rae1 Bg4 21. Re6 Bxe6 22. Rxe6 Rf6 23. Qe4 Rbf8 24. Rxf6 Rxf6 25. Qe8+ Kh7 26. Qg8+ Kh6 27. Be4 Rg6 28. Qh8+ Kg5 29. Bxg7 Be7 30. Bh6+ (30. Bh6+ Rxh6 31. Qe5#) 1-0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution in three moves.

```
[FEN "7Q/p1p1b1B1/6r1/2p3kp/4Bp1q/7P/PPP2PP1/6K1 w - - 0 1"]

1. Bh6+ Rxh6 2. Qg7+ Rg6 3. Qxg6# *
```

Comment: Even though this solution takes three moves to checkmate the black king I think it's good, since it forces a checkmate. However, for the sake of completeness, it is worth noting that there is a mate in two: 1.Bh6+!, Rxh6 2.Qe5#.

Comment: @Scounged ,even your solution is right.

Comment: Mate is possible in two moves only.

Comment: The mate in two with Bh6+, Qe5# is pretty, but the more human (easier to see) mate would be this mate in three. In fact even 1. Qh7 leads to mate and is probably what chess players would first consider.

Answer (score 0):

Bh6+ Rxh6 forced and Qe5 is then checkmate

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but it's just a repeat of what is said in [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/27530/7297), which includes a replayer for visualizing the moves. It doesn't really add any value IMHO.

Comment: I saw one incorrect answer as it used 3 moves to checkmate, and one that went through a whole game to get to the position which was not part of the question, and then had the mate in 2 as an aside. Mine is a simple answer to the question.

Comment: Fair enough ... the solution is mentioned above the diagram there, and with a small edit I was able to have the diagram start from the position in the question.